# How to configure laravel to use on hoster One.com

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-4, xampp

I recently created a website with laravel 4. I used XAMP to test my website on localhost and to make it easier I created a virtual host in the vhosts file which points to the public folder of my Laravel app. The website is working perfectly.

Now I rented a webspace at One.com hoster. I opened the webspace with ftp and when I came on the "root" but there weren't any folders so I guess that the root location is the public location? I don't for sure.

The normal structure of a Laravel app is like this:

```
--> app  
--> bootstrap  
--> public  
--> vendor  
--> other files
```

This doesn't work because I think that One.com doesn't use a public html folder. I tried to make it work but unfortunately. I moved the contents of the public folder to the root of my domain and moved all the other folders in a folder named core. Then I changed some config files index.php and paths.php but still it doesn't work.

The question is what do I need to change to my folder structure to let it work on this One.com webserver and which files I need to adapt (.htaccess, paths.php)? I would like to protect my private folders of course.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just place .htaccess file in the root folder with data below:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: Absolute hero! I can confirm this works with L5.2. Is there a way to set this so the url doesn't have `public` in it? So not `domain.com/public/` but simply `domain.com`

Answer (score 1):

one.com does use a public_html folder because that's where your files are served from.  What you can't get to is your home folder.  Xampp is a windows package - have you made sure your filenames follow case conventions? Windows being case insensitive, and Linux being sensitive.

Comment: When I access the webspace with FileZilla there is nothing to see and it says Remote site:/ so i'm on root level. When i put index.html and write something as a test it works... without a public_html folder. These folders and files were generated by laravel. Sorry I don't understand what that have to do with one.com :p. Thanks for quick response.

Comment: Xampp is not only windows. It is also a package for Linux and MacOS. And case follows the underlying OS.